# Match the same data in php foreach

Tags: php

I am trying to compare data from the two arrays together with the condition.

```
if ($ valueA == $ valueB) echo selected
```

My code looks like this

```
<select name="credit[]" data-placeholder="Credit..." class="form-control chzn-select col-lg-10" multiple tabindex="4">
<?php
  foreach ($looping_fansub->data as $looping_fansub_output) {
    foreach ($arr_credit as $credit_data) { 
      if ($credit_data==$looping_fansub_output['f_name']) {
        echo "<option value=".$looping_fansub_output["f_name"]." selected>".$looping_fansub_output["f_name"]."</option>";
      }else{
        echo "<option value=".$looping_fansub_output["f_name"]." >".$looping_fansub_output["f_name"]."</option>";
      }
    }
  }
?>
</select>

/* Array $looping_fansub->data */
Array(
        [0] => Array
            (
                [f_id] => 4
                [f_name] => AlibabaSub
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [f_id] => 7
                [f_name] => Anime Code
                [f_link] => http://anime-code.com/
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [f_id] => 2
                [f_name] => Anime Kompi
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [f_id] => 6
                [f_name] => Anti-fansubs
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [f_id] => 1
                [f_name] => AWSubs
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [f_id] => 3
                [f_name] => MoeSubs
            )
        [6] => Array
            (
                [f_id] => 5
                [f_name] => Subskun
            )
    )
/* End */
/* Array $credit_data */
    Array ( [0] => Subskun [1] => Anime Code [2] => Anime Kompi ) 
/* End */
```

I want the result to be like this:

[image]

But the result like this:

[image]

Comment: No idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: Not really clear what you want, but my guess is that you need `if(in_array($looping_fansub_output['f_name'],$arr_credit)) {..}` instead of that inner `foreach` loop.